# Only use 2 mode in Emacs with web-mode

Tags: emacs

I use web-mode in Emacs, everything is fine except that when editing a `.js.erb` file in Rails.

Because there's only 2 modes in `.js.erb` file: `js` and `ruby` and web-mode only recognize javascipt code in `<scipt type="javascript"></scipt>`.

I'm not very familiar with emacs and web-mode, maybe there's a way to config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `web-mode`'s author already fixed this, so just update your web-mode

Answer (score 3):

You can change the "default" mode of an active buffer by modifying the variable `web-mode-content-type`, e.g. from `M-:`:

```lisp
(setq web-mode-content-type "javascript")
```

Default modes may be specified by file name (or pattern) by modifying the `web-mode-content-types` alist somewhere in your configuration, e.g.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "web-mode"
  '(add-to-list 'web-mode-content-types '("javascript" . "\\.js\\.erb\\'")))
```

Comment: Do you need that `.` in `"\\.js"`?

Comment: @nymo, good eye! I originally left it out, but then I did a little bit of digging, and it [looks like `.js.erb` is a common file extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example) in Rails, even though the question makes it look like `js.erb` is a complete file name. I updated accordingly, but if I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: I think you are right and the intention was to cover files with the `.js.erb` extension... if so, then OP, ignore my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, it don't works. After I added the second snippet and restart emacs, it looks that it only use `js-mode` and the ruby code don't highlight.

Comment: @Eorza, hrm, you're correct. That's the same behaviour that `web-mode` gives for `.js` files. I haven't found any other promising options.